# How to make external HTTP requests with Node.js

Tags: http, node.js

The question is fairly simple. I want to use a Node.js server as a proxy to log, authenticate, and forward HTTP queries to a backend HTTP server (PUT, GET, and DELETE requests).

What library should I use for that purpose? I'm afraid I can't find one.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

NodeJS supports http.request as a standard module:
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/http.html#http.request

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/foo.html'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
    //do something with chunk
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend adding `resp.setEncoding('utf8');` (or whatever encoding you're using) to get data as utf8 strings. If I have understood right, otherwise you'll get Buffer objects and might end up having trouble with multi-byte characters if a multi-byte character is split to two chunks. (Just debugged a related problem for a while)

Comment: I've actually started using `request` npm module a lot more.

Answer (score 7):

I would combine [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and [express](http://expressjs.com/).

node-http-proxy will support a proxy inside your node.js web server via `RoutingProxy` (see the example called *Proxy requests within another http server*).

Inside your custom server logic you can do authentication using express. See the [auth sample here for an example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js).

Combining those two examples should give you what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in `http` module to do an `http.request()`.

However if you want to simplify the API you can use a module such as [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/)

Comment: Much saner api indeed. I don't blame node for providing only low level API but starting to handle chunks of data is just plain annoying.

Answer (score 1):

node-http-proxy is a great solution as was suggested by @hross above. If you're not deadset on using node, we use [NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/) to do the same thing. It works really well with node. We use it for example to process SSL requests before forwarding them to node. It can also handle cacheing and forwarding routes. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js http module to do that. You could check the documentation at [Node.js HTTP](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#http.request).

You would need to pass the query string as well to the other HTTP Server. You should have that in [ServerRequest.url](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#http.ServerRequest).

Once you have those info, you could pass in the backend HTTP Server and port in the options that you will provide in the `http.request()`