# Forward request to alternate request handler instead of redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.js with express and already know the existence of `response.redirect()`.

However, I'm looking for more of a `forward()` functionality similar to java that takes the same parameters as redirect, but internally forwards the request instead of having the client perform the redirect.

To clarify, I am not doing a proxy to a different server. I'd like to `forward('/other/path')` directly within the same app instance

It wasn't apparently obvious how to do this from the express documentation. Any help?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967037/how-to-make-external-http-requests-with-node-js

Comment: to clarify, I am not doing a proxy to a different server. I'd like to forward('/other/path') directly within the same app instance

Answer (score 26):

You just need to invoke the corresponding route handler function.

### Option 1: route multiple paths to the same handler function

```
function getDogs(req, res, next) {
  //...
}}
app.get('/dogs', getDogs);
app.get('/canines', getDogs);
```

### Option 2: Invoke a separate handler function manually/conditionally

```
app.get('/canines', function (req, res, next) {
   if (something) {
      //process one way
   } else {
      //do a manual "forward"
      getDogs(req, res, next);
   }
});
```

### Option 3: call `next('route')`

If you carefully order your router patterns, you can call `next('route')`, which may achieve what you want. It basically says to express 'keep moving on down the router pattern list', instead of a call to `next()`, which says to express 'move down the middleware list (past the router)`.

Comment: Let's assume the use case as follows: User logs in, but the app redirects them to a login page while saving the url they were intending to go to. After they log in, I retrieve the original url they intended to go to and want to "forward" them there. I know technically, it is better to redirect, but for the sake of argument i don't want them to make an extra request. How would any of the options above solve that? In essence, I feel like I need a way to retrieve the mapping of urls to handlers in express and somehow write my own forward function based on it.

Answer (score 23):

You can implement **forward** (aka **rewrite**) functionality by changing request `url` property and calling `next('route')`.

Note that the handler performing forward needs to be configured before other routes which you perform forwards to.

This is example of *forwarding* all `*.html` documents to routes without `.html` extension (suffix).

```
function forwards(req, res, next) {
    if (/(?:.+?)\.html$/.test(req.url)) {
        req.url = req.url.replace(/\.html$/, '');
    }
    next('route');
}
```

You call `next('route')` as the last operation. The `next('route')` passes control to subsequent routes.

As mentioned above, you need to configure forwards handler as one of the first handlers.

```
app.get('*', forwards);
// ...
app.get('/someroute', handler);
```

The above example will return the same content for `/someroute` as well as `/someroute.html`. You could also provide an object with a set of forward rules (`{ '/path1': '/newpath1', '/path2': '/newpath2' }`) and use them in *forward* mechanism.

Note that regular expression used in `forwards` function is simplified for mechanism presentation purposes. You would need to extend it (or perform check on `req.path`) if you would like to use querystring parameters etc.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 16):

**For Express 4+**

Using the `next` function does not work if the next handler is not added in the right order. Instead of using `next`, I use the router to register the handlers and call

```
app.get("/a/path", function(req, res){
    req.url = "/another/path";
    app.handle(req, res);
}
```

Or for HTML5 mode of React/Angular

```
const dir = process.env.DIR || './build';

// Configure http server
let app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(dir));

// This route sends a 404 when looking for a missing file (ie a URL with a dot in it)
app.all('/*\.*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('404 Not found');
});

// This route deals enables HTML5Mode by forwarding "missing" links to the index.html
app.all('/**', function (req, res) {
    req.url = 'index.html';
    app.handle(req, res);
});
```

Comment: What if my router handlers aren't in the same file?

Comment: Should be using `req.app.handle(req, res)` instead, which allows your router handlers to be in a different file

Answer (score 12):

Using the `next` function does not work if the next handler is not added in the right order. Instead of using `next`, I use the router to register the handlers and call

```
router.get("/a/path", function(req, res){
    req.url = "/another/path";
    router.handle(req, res);
}
```

Comment: router is deprecated on Express 4+

Comment: instead of router.get and router.handle, I use app.get and app.handle in Express 4+ and it works like a charm! Saved me! This should be marked as the right answer because it's the only right answer here.

Comment: @Manny I'm confused `let router = require('express').Router();` is deprecated in Express 4+?

Comment: **For Express 4+** instead of using `router.handle` use `req.app.handle`

Answer (score 4):

**Express 4+ with nested routers**

Instead of having to use the outside of route/function **`app`**, you can use **`req.app.handle`**

```js
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//
//  Nested Router 1
//
const routerOne = express.Router();

//  /one/base
routerOne.get("/base", function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("/one/base");
});

//  This routes to same router (uses same req.baseUrl)
//  /one/redirect-within-router -> /one/base
routerOne.get("/redirect-within-router", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/base";
  next();
});

//  This routes to same router (uses same req.baseUrl)
//  /one/redirect-not-found -> /one/two/base (404: Not Found)
routerOne.get("/redirect-not-found", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/two/base";
  next();
});

//  Using the full URL
//  /one/redirect-within-app -> /two/base
routerOne.get("/redirect-within-app", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/two/base";

  // same as req.url = "/one/base";
  //req.url = req.baseUrl + "/base";

  req.app.handle(req, res);
});

//  Using the full URL
//  /one/redirect-app-base -> /base
routerOne.get("/redirect-app-base", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = "/base";
  req.app.handle(req, res);
});



//
//  Nested Router 2
//
const routerTwo = express.Router();

//  /two/base
routerTwo.get("/base", function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("/two/base");
});

//  /base
app.get("/base", function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("/base");
});


//
//  Mount Routers
//
app.use("/one/", routerOne);
app.use("/two/", routerTwo);


//  404: Not found
app.all("*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("404: Not Found");
});
```

Comment: Next doesn't work like that. The next function simply sends the request to the next handler...

Comment: From the [Express 4 documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl):  _"(req.originalUrl) This property is much like req.url; however, it retains the original request URL, allowing you to rewrite req.url freely for internal routing purposes."_

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get('/menzi', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('menzi2');
        req.url = '/menzi/html/menzi.html';
        // res.redirect('/menzi/html/menzi.html');
        next();
});
```

This is my code:when user enter "/menzi",the server will give the page /menzi/html/menzi.html to user, but the url in the browser will not change;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `run-middleware` module exactly for that. Just run the handler you want by using the URL & method & data.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-middleware

For example:

```
app.runMiddleware('/get-user/20',function(code,body,headers){
    res.status(code).send(body)
})
```