# Anyway I can get the html body in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I try to send a request to an Apache server and use the returned body.

Follow the manual of nodejs 
http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

and related SO content
[How to make external HTTP requests with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967037/how-to-make-external-http-requests-with-node-js)

My src is

```
callback = function(response) {
  body='';
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body+= chunk;
  }); 

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(body);
  }); 
}
```

My question is that the body here will include all the HTML header tag, such as  `<!DOCTYPE html>`...etc, which cannot be parsed by JSON object. Because all my data in the HTML body is JSOn, I want to get only the HTML body. Are there anyway to achieve this goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused. Whatever returned is already HTML only, right?

Comment: response body is not HTML page body. You would have to scrape the page to extract <body> contents and then JSON.parse it.

Comment: There are some package for html query in node.js: cherio or jquery. https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio

Comment: @thefourtheye You are right, but I am trying to get the 'body' of HTML

Comment: @vkurchatkin Sorry, that is a mistake.

Comment: @StevenR So, you are only interested in everything insider `<body>`?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, it is a json.

Comment: In the end, I can get the json only by set the HTTP header "Accept" to "application/json"

Comment: @StevenR In that case my answer would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not giving complete code here.

1. You can use modules like [`htmlparser2`](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) to extract the data from HTML's body ([`Online demo for the same`](http://demos.forbeslindesay.co.uk/htmlparser2/)).
2. And then you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the extracted string to a JSON Object.

Comment: Thanks! I will also try this one.

Comment: @StevenR This is the way to go. There may be some regex based solutions, but they are not reliable. If you want to extract data from HTML, you just have to parse it.