# how to make an HTTP get request using nodejs HTTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a reference error because I cannot use XMLHttpRequest.

Is there a way to make a get http request to grab all the data from my mongodb?

GET from `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts`?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967037/how-to-make-external-http-requests-with-node-js)

Comment: How do I store the chunk that is returned?  I want to be able to do Object.keys(the data).map(some function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you my friend. however, just one question.  I am receiving errors after doing the npm install, and after running my server - it is ssaying that it cannot find modules 'net' and 'tls'.  What to do?  Are these required?  It is returning my JSON data, but throwing these errors into my console.

Comment: @user1354934 I'm not sure about this, just tried to install this package and created a simple file with example I posted and everything works great.